# Python pip / pip3 install failure CodecRegistryError

Tags: python, command, installation

I am trying to install pyglet without going insane. I have not installed any previous versions of Python before 3.6.0

from command prompt, I can run

```
>Python
```

and it functions correctly. When I try pip or pip3 install i get a

```
'raise CodecRegistryError,\
Syntax error: invalid syntax
```

I uninstalled python completely and reinstalled, to no success.

I am using Windows 10, and PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a python3 problem that occurs when the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` is set.  For pylauncher, in these cases, to get python3 to run, you apply

```
py -E ....
```

For pip, I got the same error, then the error went away when I removed the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks your system does not recognize the pip command, so try to add the path to pip in your environment variables.
- go to system
- advanced system setting
- environment variables
and in the user variables PATH add the path to the python scripts folder.
I looks something like this: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\

But it can happen that pip is not installed with your version of python, if you can not find pip in the folder above, try to install pip with easyinstall.

Comment: Or maybe it is because pyglet does not work with python 3.6.0 yet.